# How to call LinkedIn authorize javascript from button

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

This line of sample code from LinkedIn API works perfectly.

```
<script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="loadData"></script>
```

but it runs automatically as the web page loads.  I'd like to invoke this script using a button or link on a webpage.  The idea being that the webpage loads and waits until the user is ready to authenticate.

Ideally I would like the LinkedIn Login image to appear, and wait, until clicked.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say it runs automatically, do you mean that the script tag displays the LinkedIn login button automatically on page load? Would you like to only show the above button when the user clicks another button?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks Paul.  Help appreciated.  I want to wrap the script above in a button, but it's the change of "type" that's confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, it looks like you only want to display the [SignIn plugin](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sign-linkedin) if the user has manually clicked a button/element on the page. Something like this, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), should work:

On your page, you have a button:

```
<div id="buttonControl">
  <input type="button" id="showLinkedIn" value="Show LinkedIn" onclick="showLinkedIn();" />
</div>
<div id="buttonContent" style="display: none;"></div>
```

In a script block in the `<head>` of the page, you have the `showLinkedIn()` `onclick` function:

```
function showLinkedIn() {
  // insert the SignIn plugin
  $('#buttonContent').html('<script type="IN/Login" data-onauth="loadData"><\/script>');

  // tell the LinkedIn JavaScript code to re-parse the element containing the SignIn plugin
  IN.parse($('#buttonContent')[0]);

  // hide button trigger, if needed
  $('#buttonControl').hide();

  // show the LinkedIn control
  $('#buttonContent').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#buttonControl').click(function(){
    $('#buttonContent').html('<script type="IN/Login" data-onauth="loadData"></script>');
    $('#buttonControl,#buttonContent').toggle();
    IN.User.authorize(loadData);
    });
```

slightly different as the 'IN.parse($('#buttonContent')[0]);' does not seem to work...

tested 'IN.User.authorize(loadData)' and it works well! Got it from: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inauth-inevent-and-inui

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the cookies from the following method like

```
IN.User.logout(callbackFunction, callbackScope);
```

You need to call this function on that button from which you want to log out.

Example using jquery:

```
$('#demo') .click(function() 
{
    IN.User.logout(console.log("logged out..."));
});
```